# Update current model value while using bindings

Tags: angularjs

New to angular, so I hope I am asking this question correctly.

(Angular 1.5 and using components)

**Parent.html:**

```
<names on-refresh-names='$ctrl.reloadNames'></names>
```

**Parent.js**

```
this.reloadNames = function() {
...
}
```

**Names.html**

```
<input ng-model="searchNameValue">
<button ng-click='$ctrl.onRefreshNames()'></button>
```

**Names.js**
...

```
component.bindings = { onRefreshNames: '&' }
```

I want to make the input with the search string to be cleared (`searchNameValue = '';`) when the onRefreshNames is executed. But it is executed in the parent and the `searchNameValue` is in the child.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine statements into one expression:

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.onRefreshNames(); searchNameValue = '';"></button>
```

But in this case it makes sense to move them both into a function in your component controller:

```
<input ng-model="$ctrl.searchNameValue">
<button ng-click="$ctrl.onRefresh()"></button>
```

where in controller

```
this.onRefresh = function() {
  this.onRefreshNames()
  this.searchNameValue = ''
}
```

In any case, note that in parent view it should be

```
<names on-refresh-names="$ctrl.reloadNames()"></names>
```

Comment: The first part is the easiest way I was looking for. Also I tried the second part, using function in my names controller - this was also useful. But I couldn't clear the input by this.searchNameValue = '', I had to use $scope.searchNameValue instead. Is that how it should work or I missed something in your answer?

Comment: It's better not to use `$scope` if the rest of methods are bound to controller instance (this). For `this.searchNameValue = ''` to work make sure you have `ng-model="$ctrl.searchNameValue"` in HTML (note $ctrl part).

Comment: Indeed. Got it working without $scope as you suggested using the second approach. That solve it. Thank you.